# How do I find out my CD ROM hardware specifics on FreeBSD?

Tags: hardware, freebsd, dmesg

I can usually use `dmesg` soon after bootup to display hardware info that my kernel loads. After my system has been up for a while however, `dmesg` no longer produces anything of value concerning hardware. How can I find out my hardware specifics, such as what kind of CD ROM drive I have, that is usually found by `dmesg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SATA and ATA drives `atacontrol info ata#` where # is the channel number found by `atacontrol list`

For SCSI drives and those passed through with `atapicam` you can pull info with `camcontrol inq dev0` where dev0 is the device name (like cd0, or da0 for hard drives). And `camcontrol devlist` will list all the devices.

Answer (score -1):

```
lshal
```

This lists very detailed information about all hardware including the CD/DVD drive. ( note this is on linux however I suspect there is a freeBSD port/equivalent )

Comment: You're command has no power here. Begone before someone drops a house on you.

Comment: I stand shamed.